# JAXB jar maintaining element order?

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I wanted to confirm whether JAXB will maintain element order as is stated in the schema file?

For example: Below is an extract from an XSD file which I am using to unmarshall XML.

```
<xs:sequence>  
      <xs:element name="stateID" type="xs:string"/>  
      <xs:element name="countryCode" type="xs:string"/>  
</xs:sequence>
```

Will JAXB ensure that the `stateID` element comes before the `countryCode` element?

Comment: I  am not sure that i understand what you are asking, especailly JAXB jar confuses me, but i can assure thar the sequence tag is for maintaining order only.. so i dont think you should worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

In JAXB the `propOrder` property on the `@XmlType` annotation is used to specify the order that a JAXB impl will follow.  If your JAXB model was generated from an XML schema then it will contain this annotation.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxbs-xmltype-and-proporder.html